# What is the value of uppercase "KB" in Computer Science? What is difference between uppercase "KB" and lowercase "kb" in CS?

Tags: download, binary, download-speed

Am I correct:

Lowercase k is equal to 1000 in CS
and
Uppercase K is equal to 1024 in CS?

Answer (score 0):

KB stands for "Kilobytes" which is a storage measure.

kb, on the other hand, stands for "kilobits" which is a common measure for internet speed.

I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Is 1Mb equal to 1000Kb or 1024Kb?

Comment: The reason you see some measures from 1000 to 1000 and other from 1024 to 1024 is because hardware companies calculate and sell from 100 to 1000, but operaring systems read from 1024 to 1024. That's the same reason why your USB memory, for example, stands "16GB" on the packet, but when you plug in your computer you read less that 16GB.